# Why should we separate dimension and facts instead of combining both in one table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

need some insight in dimensional modeling or star schema.

Normally, when we design data warehouse we will have fact tables and dimension tables.

However, it does make sense to embed dimension in fact table. Especially for simple dimensions who has no other attributes AND rarely change its value.

Having dimensions in fact table will makes query run very fast and no need to maintain dimension table separately, no need to look up dimension table when doing ETL.

Is there any consideration keep dimensions separated from facts?

Comment: actually it is about to embed all dimensions in fact, not only degenerate dimension

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Facts have LOTS of rows. If you put an attribute of, say, length 20 in a fact, more storage is required than if you put stored just an `INT` surrogate key (4 bytes). More storage = bigger table = decreased performance.
2. You almost always want to store other hierarchies and attributes against a given attribute. Even if you don't now, you might want to in future
3. Generally in reporting you'll have a list of these attributes in a drop down to filter on. How do you get these out of a fact? `SELECT DISTINCT` on a very large table, which is expensive without indexes. With indexes, you're impacting your load performance.

When you put stuff in dimensions instead of facts it means you've done some kind of analysis about how this fits into the business

Comment: Nicely put, +1. However, sometimes, it's not a bad idea to de-generate your dimension and put the attributes in the fact table itself to make query work faster. As an example, consider a `receipt number` in a `sales fact` table. Instead of storing it in a separate `receipt` dimension, you can as well put it in the fact table itself.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In that case you wouldn't put it in a dimension

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
1. i think performance is about table index size, not table size per se, cmiiw

2. i see, what if i just add another column in the future to represent the hieararchy

3. this might be incrementally build when doing ETL, however this will only be reference and no need to join with fact. what do you think?

Comment: 1. Indexes still have to go and lookup the page when the value you need is not in the index. If you need two pages instead of one to store the rows you need thats not good. I'm sure there are many edge cases where this isn't true though. 2. Then when you update/manage the hierarchy you need to update a large fact table, not a small dimension. Your dimension maintenance just got 10 times slower 3. Do you mean you'll go and populate a little helper table off to the side during ETL? you mean like a dimension ?!! Why do half the job.

Comment: PS these are only arguments against (as requested).... there are many arguments for. As usual it's a 'it depends' scenario. In my current project I am storing attributes on the fact because I don't have budget/time to build a dimension... so there's one non technical reason to store attributes on the fact.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - can you please share some insight on business case when fact and dimension have 121 relationship. e.g. customer deposited money to account. We have amount, accountNumber and customer? DimDeposit and FactDeposit would have 121 relationship. Does it make sense to combine both tables into one?

Comment: Surely customers make more than one deposit? And you wouldn't have a FactDeposit, you'd have a FactTransaction, so it captures withdrawals, interest etc. as well. So I can't see this ever being 1 to 1. Regardless, if you ever do find a case where there really is a 1-1 appearing between fact and dimension, I do recommend putting the info in the fact. 1 to 1 between fact and dimension aren't common though.